# Drupal login and adding node

Tags: c#, drupal

Is there any possibility to use C# for logging into drupal CMS and add a node to some category?
How to do it? Any documentations or examples are welcome.

Comment: C# is a programming language. I cannot draw the line between a pure programming language and a CMS plattform (let alone that it is being developed in PHP).

Comment: i want to write a program, which will automatically logging to my drupal site and add some node. I saw something similar for Wordpress with C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to use one of the services modules. [Services](http://drupal.org/project/services) probably has more documentation.

- [RESTful Web Services](http://drupal.org/project/restws)
- [Services](http://drupal.org/project/services)